# How to produce a PSF for out of focus blur using matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have written a matlab code to produce a PSF for out of focus blur of size 512x512. The problem is that I receive a black square as the output. What can I try to fix this?

```
a = 512; b = 512;
k = 0; l = 0;
PSF = zeros(a,b);
r = 0.001;

for i = 1:a
    for j = 1:b
        
        if (i-k)^2+(j-l)^2 <= r^2
           PSF(i,j) = 1/(pi*r^2);
        else
            PSF(i,j) = 0;
        end
        
    end
end    
    
figure(1); imshow(PSF);
```

Comment: `for i = 1` to what? I guess you meant `for i=1:a`, right?

Comment: Yes, I edited this. Sorry. it was a typing mistake.

Comment: Did it solve your problem? If not, edit your question again and set values of `a` and `b`.

Comment: No, it did not solve the problem. I edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: Seems that you want to draw some filled circle. Note that `i` and `j` start from 1 and increase by 1. Now, you specified the radius as 0.001 **pixels**. So none of the pixels will be inside the circle. You need to either increase the radius or decrease the steps.

Comment: @saastn Yes, that is true  but if I increase the reduis r,  the value 1/(pi*r^2) becomes so small and no circle is shown. I also tried with different values for the center (k,l). If I replace 1/(pi*r^2) with for example 0.5, I do receive a circle but to reconstruct a PSF for out of focus blur I must use 1/(pi*r^2).

Comment: So you must have some resolution. Meaning `r` must be in some other unit rather than pixel. If so, you need to generate some `x` and `y`. Because `i` and `j` are pixel indices and are too big to create a circle of radius 0.001.

Comment: @saastn Yes, exactly, you are right.  I also noticed this problem and changed the values of a and b to [0,1] (for exmaple I wrote a = linspace(0,1,512)) and r to 0.15 and the problem is solved. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the Matlab Image Toolbox, it's possible to create a PSF like this with [fspecial('disk', radius)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/fspecial.html), where `radius` is in units of pixels.

In your code, beware as saastn pointed out that the disk radius `r` of 0.001 pixels is extremely small. Also, the disk is centered on (0,0), outside of the domain {1,...,a} × {1,...,b} that the loop evaluates the PSF over. It looks like you meant something like `k = (1 + a)/2, l = (1 + b)/2` to put the disk in the center.